# Java: Why does my external program being run freeze when called within Java?

Tags: java

I am calling an external application from my Java GUI.  The Java code is below when the user hits the "RUN" button in the GUI:

```
Runtime runme = Runtime.getRuntime();
runme.exec("MyApp.bin");
```

MyApp.bin does some math calculations and has some loops in it - no big deal.  What happens is that MyApp.bin gets stuck!  When I close my Java GUI, then MyApp.bin continues to run and finishes.  If I run MyApp.bin directly from the terminal, then it runs fine without freezing.  Why does my application freeze when it is run from the Java GUI, but resumes when I close the Java GUI?  What is the Java GUI or Java code doing that is blocking my application from running successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to make a wild guess that `MyApp.bin` is outputting something to its standard out, and you're not reading it. This causes the buffer to fill, and blocks your process.

`Runtime.exec()` returns a `Process` object. If you read the javadoc for that you'll find:

> The created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All
>   its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be
>   redirected to the parent process through three streams
>   (getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), getErrorStream()). The parent
>   process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the
>   subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer
>   size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write
>   the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause
>   the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: This sounds like the problem!  My app does output some numbers.  Looks like I need to look into getOutputStream(), per your link.

Comment: Yup - you need to read the output even if you're not going to do anything with it. In a GUI application you generally want to do all of this in its own thread so as not to block the main event handling thread.